# Nuxt Auth strategy doesn't fetch authentication token

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I have the following authentication strategy:

```js
auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        ...,
      },
      google: {
        clientId:
          "<MY CLIENT ID>",
        responseType: "code",
        endpoints: {
          token: "http://localhost:8000/social-login/google/",
          userInfo: "http://localhost:8000/auth/user/",
        },
      },
    },
    redirect: {
      ...
    },
  },
```

Oddly enough, this strategy completes all the authentication by itself, without ever hitting my backend! Shouldn't responseType `code` go to `endpoints.token` to get the token?

My login function looks like this:

```js
    loginWithGoogle() {
      this.$auth.loginWith("google", {
        params: {
          client_id:
            "<MY CLIENT ID>",
        },
      });
    },
```

Interestingly enough, if I don't pass the params here, Google gives me an error that `client_id` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with `@nuxtjs/auth`, which is the version <= `v4.9.1`, and as the documentation [warns](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/status) that it may contain bugs and un-implemented functionalities.

Using `v5`, named `@nuxtjs/auth-next` would fix the issue.

Install as:

```
yarn add --exact @nuxtjs/auth-next
```

Then add to your `nuxt.config.js` as (from the [documentation](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup)):

```js
{
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
  ],
  auth: {
    // Options
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, try to stick to a specific version to avoid too much issues/breaking changes.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is wrong. Use client_id , redirect_uri , etc, snake case instead, this worked for me